# Execute a command with relative path and save the return value of the command in a batch script

Tags: batch-file, cmd, tortoisesvn

I need to execute the command "svnversion" from within a batch script to get the current revision of my svn folder.

If i only run the command it gets executed outside my svn folder. So I need to run the command svnversion from my folder.

I was trying something like

```
@echo off
set PATH=%cd%
echo %PATH% // Just for debugging purpose
for /f "delims=" %%i in ("%PATH%" 'svnversion') do set VERSION=%%i
@echo %VERSION%
```

What I want is to go to path e.g "C:\Folder\SVN\trunk" and execute the command "svnversion" and save the return value it returns.

If i run my script form the cmd it works without involving the path, but the batch script is executed in my build environment and the path seems to be wrong when I compile my project for the batch script.

Comment: **Never** (over-)write the `PATH` variable, it is used by the system to find executables!

Answer (score -3):

Figured it out, just add cd %~pd0

```
@echo off
cd %~pd0
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('svnversion') do set VERSION=%%i
@echo %VERSION%
```

Comment: please try harder, read your code back and see if you can spot any mistakes.

Comment: Don't really understand what you mean by that. It works as I wish right now and actually I'm quite satisfied with that,

Comment: I can understand that mistakes are made, but now you've had chance to review it and still believe it to be correct. I'll spell it out for you; your code is wrong!

Comment: I understand from your comment that something was wrong with the code above. As I have little knowledge with batch script (could have declared that better) just pointing out that something is wrong doesn't really help much. I also never stated that I believe it is correct, but that it works.

Comment: Oh thank you aschipfl, I didn't copy and paste my solution and accidently made a typo. Will edit it!

Comment: You would be better off using the PUSHD command to change the directory.